# multi query execution

Tags: database

i want to implement store procedure in drupal 6, i need database(mysql) connection to execute `$mysqli->multi_query($query)` currently i am creating new connection every time when my function called.
Here in my function for this,

```
function test($journal_id, $ebook_id, $table_name)
{
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','sanjay');
$query = "CALL GetFreeOpenAccessVolumeList1($journal_id, $ebook_id,'$table_name')"; #     if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) { 

if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
     while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) 
     {

        $arr[] = $row->content_type_id;
     }
    $result->free();
    $mysqli->next_result();
  }
} 
else 
{
  drupal_set_message("An error ocurred in your module while calling the   
   sp_yourstoredprocedure stored procedure. MySQL error: ".mysqli_error(), 'warning');
}


return $arr;
}
```

Comment: Answered in the docs at Drupal.org http://drupal.org/node/18429

Comment: i want to know about multi query execution in drupal, as we have default  `mysql->multi_query($query);`

Comment: So, you wanna bypass Drupal's database system altogether?

Comment: actually i have did that because i didn't found other option, i didn't found any drupal function for executing multi query its api, so i want to know what drupal suggest for this, @Mołot

Comment: Drupal does not support multi_query, but does support multiple databases. And if you want something to be accessible during the whole call, consider Singletons. But that's just pure PHP, Drupal-unrelated.

Comment: what do you suggest for implementing store procedure in drupal, does drupal support store procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current connection object through the [`$active_db`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/active_db/6) global.

It's been a million years since I used old-school mysql(i) methods and I can't remember if you can instantiate a new `MySQLi` object from that connection object; Drupal uses the procedural method itself (see [`_db_query()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.mysqli.inc/function/_db_query/6)), as in this example:

```
global $active_db;
$query = "CALL GetFreeOpenAccessVolumeList1($journal_id, $ebook_id,'$table_name')";
$result = mysqli_query($active_db, $query);
```

Someone has implemented a `db_query_call()` function which will probably give you everything you need to call stored procedures:

http://drupal.org/node/119781#comment-2904142

Altering it to use the current instantiated connection should be trivial.